# Change Inno Setup radio button (licence agreement) font color

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

I am trying to change color of text of radio buttons in the License Agreement page in `WizardForm`.
I changed the background to black and want the texts white.

Here is my code:

```pascal
WizardForm.LicenseAcceptedRadio.Font.Color := clWhite; 
WizardForm.LicenseNotAcceptedRadio.Font.Color := clWhite;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible to do it unless you subclass that control. Radio button appearance is controlled by the Windows theme.

One alternative is to create a radio button with no caption and use a label together with it. In that way you can modify the colors of the label.